# String Equal to Regex Result?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex result I would like to capture in order to use it throughout my code. Such as, i'm using regex to get rid of a specific part in a string and i'd like to capture the result in string variable.

Is it even possible to do such a thing? And how does one even go about it?

Input:

`C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\W_11052_0_X.pts`

Expected Result that I want to store into a string:

`C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\`

Regex Pattern: 
`^(.*[\\])`

Comment: Please provide us examples and what you've tried.

Comment: So you want to store a regex capture and use it in other places for comparison?

Comment: @Zekth I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to go about this.

Comment: @BradChristie I suppose so?

Comment: Please provide us examples with input and expected results.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using regex rather than (what appears to just need) [`Path.GetDirectoryName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getdirectoryname.aspx)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it's honestly a long story... ut Path.GetDirectoryName() doesn't return the correct results I need in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can: `Groups` property of the `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match` object lets you access the match in the form of a `string` by accessing the `Value` property of the corresponding group.

For example, you can do this to capture the value of the expected output from your example:

```
string nameString = @"C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\W_11052_0_X.pts";
// Note that I needed to double the slashes in your pattern to avoid the "unmatched [" error
string pathPrefix = Regex.Match(nameString, @"^(.*[\\])").Groups[1].Value;
Console.WriteLine(pathPrefix);
```

The above prints

```
C:\Users\Documents\Development\testing\11.0.25.10\
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/68VVnD).

Comment: you should append `Value` after `Groups[1]` or change `numbericId`'s type to `Group`.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks! I was too sloppy typing it up from memory. Once I tried it out, this error has revealed itself pretty quickly :-)